# How to hardcode TextView aligment distance from start?

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment

I have a layout with white background and big textViews with darkblue background and white text.
I want to give some space to the text from the start of the darkblue background rectangle.

I already tried but only can set start, center, end, top, etc; and I want to specify it numerically.
How I can meet that goal?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved by specifying the padding value on the TextView. Look for `android:padding` attribute. If you want to give some space from the start, you can use `android:paddingStart` attribute on the TextView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works! But for compatibility with older versions Android Studio suggest me to change it to **android:paddingLeft="7sp"** Can I have both or should I use only the older version?

Comment: **sp** should be used only for determining the size of a text. You should use **dp** instead of sp to define the padding value. If you want compatibility with older versions of Android, then you can use `android:paddingLeft` as suggested by Android Studio. In newer/recent version, Android Studio will highlight this as warning and recommend you to use `android:paddingStart`, but using the older `paddingLeft` is still permitted and your app will still work well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably setting margin to your layout might help

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0); //move 10 px to right (increase left margin)substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
tv.setLayoutParams(params);//tv.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

im not sure if this is excatly what you are looking for